# 'sed' Command doesn't work with java script

Tags: javascript, shell, sed

I want to exectue following Shell Command with the Execute Option form Javascript:

```
"sed -i 4r<(sed '1,5!d' /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_template.template) /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"
```

Then i try this command in the shell console it works perfektly. But after starting it with the .js programm nothing is happen. I just want to copy the first 5 lines in template and add them to the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `exec` from `child_process`

```js
const exec = require('child_process').exec
exec("sed -i 4r<(sed '1,5!d' /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_template.template) /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
       return console.error(err)
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
})
```

Comment: i already tried it with the child_progress. My code looks similar to the one you have sent. And the exec() funktion ist also working with echo, cat and other funktions but then im try to add the sed command nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to execute any shell command and replace the o/p to a new file(create a new file) everytime you run it. And, you should use the line-reader module to get the line from the files.

```
npm install --save line-reader
```

```
const fs = require('fs');
const lineReader = require('line-reader');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const cmd = "sed -i 4r<(sed '1,5!d' /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_template.template) /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"

exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    //some err occurred
    console.error(err)
  } else {
   // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
   fs.writeFile('file path', stdout, (err) => {
    // throws an error, you could also catch it here
    if (err) throw err;
    // success case, the file was saved
    console.log('file saved');
    readFile1();
  });
  }
});

const readFile1 = () => lineReader.eachLine('file path', function(line) {
  //make logic to take number of lines you want to take.
  console.log(line);
});
```

Comment: I have nearly the same code, but the exec("sed -i 4r<(sed '1,5!d' /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_template.template) /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf") command didn´t work maybe the ' makes problems with java script.

Comment: I start the skript from my raspi can you maybe tell me where i can open the logs und view the logs?

Comment: You can run the above script and add an output file in same directory. Save the above code in any node script and run it using node filename and you will see any errors if they come up. It seems like your cmd doesn't o/p anything. I did the same with sed simple command and it shows the log.

Comment: So after i installt an simple node Programm i noticed, that i had an "(" error this i could fix with define one veriable. But than i have an missing initalisation. /home/pi/simpleaudio/test.js:3
exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

Comment: Have you installed the node correctly? did you init the package.json and installed the dependencies? Once you do that then try to run above code with simple shell command